# Cannot find symbol when compile both source and test file together

Tags: netbeans

I am taking Java class 101, and used NetBeans as IDE. I created source file (GradeBook.java) and test file GreadeBookTest.java).  In GreadeBooKTest class when call to GradeBook class, it gives cannot file symbol (of GradeBook). Both files are exact copy from text book, not created by me. When tried to compile then using cmd I get java:24:error Cannot find symbol.

I read through most posts here and followed the instruction of moving both file into same directory and compiled them together and I also tried with javac *.java and all got same error.  I have this same problem with any pair of files I created in NetBeans.  Not sure if there is something I don't know about how to use NetBeans.

D:\Jave\Test javac *.java

GreadeBookTest.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
        GradeBook myGradeBook = new GradeBook();

symbol:   class GradeBook

location: class GreadeBookTest

Comment: Do either file use packages?

Comment: Every file created in NetBeans has its own package.

Comment: If your 2 classes are in different packages, then your GradeBookTest class needs to import GradeBook

Comment: import java.util.GradeBook;  and got error right on the spot of cannot find symbol

Comment: Thank you John for your help.  I did import gradbook.GradeBook, and I passed the error.